# Get to development environment

Tags: lightning-experience, setup, menu

How could I get to development environment from the main page (the page is shown below)?
[image]

In other words, I want to get to lightning setup from the page. As you can see on the screenshot I am already logged in.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once logged in, you can click on "Your name" (top-right corner), then "My Developer Account." Or, at any time, you can go to the main [login page](https://login.salesforce.com/) and log in directly from there.